# Unable to access ViewBag in JQuery Dialog in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

Can't access the viewBag Data inside the Dialog window.  Outside of Dialog displays User ID, but inside of Dialog not displaying the UserID
Script

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 339,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 700
            }
        });
    });

    function OpenDialog()
    {
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");
    }
</script>

<div id="open" onclick="OpenDialog();">Click To Open</div>  

  @ViewBag.UserID
    <div id="dialog">   
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User ID</td>
                    <td>@ViewBag.UserID</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comments</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextArea("CommentsTextBox")</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="alignCenter"> 
                 <input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
                 <input type="button" value="Cancel" /> 
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it is listed I dont see anything wrong with your cshtml.

http://dotnetfiddle.net/clz3Md

Comment: I have updated my question can you check it now? ViewBag not displaying value inside the JQuery Dialog

Comment: you should also add a type attribute to your script decleration http://dotnetfiddle.net/6yWqQo